# What is the meaning of <number>d or <number>f in oracle?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Here is the normal execution to select `100` from the dual table:

```
SQL> select 100 from dual;

       100
----------
       100
```

Here is the same execution adding `'a'` to the number `100` which just sets the column name. The result will be same for any other alphabets except d and f.

```
SQL> select 100a from dual;

         A
----------
       100
```

Here is the same execution adding `'d'` and `'f'` to the number `100`

```
SQL> select 100d from dual;

      100D
----------
  1.0E+002

SQL> select 100f from dual;

      100F
----------
  1.0E+002
```

Where is it useful? What does it mean?

Comment: It should be `select 100 a from dual` in order to set an alias for the `100` column. Notice there is a space between the expression and the alias. That space makes the difference between `100 f` (integer `100` aliased as `f`) and `100f` (floating point `100.0`, no alias).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`d` and `f` are there to implicitly declare the number as a **floating-point**.

`1.0E+002` is the [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation) for 100

`100a` is just interpreted by oracle as number value `100` aliased `a`.

---

Official doc [NUMBER and Floating-Point Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#i139891)

[image]

> **f** or **F** indicates that the number is a 32-bit binary floating point
>   number (of type BINARY_FLOAT).
>
> **d** or **D** indicates that the number is a 64-bit binary floating point
>   number (of type BINARY_DOUBLE)

---

An example of this behavior can be found in the [ROUND() function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions135.htm) doc

> The following examples illustrate the difference between rounding
>   NUMBER and **floating-point number** values. NUMBER values are rounded up
>   (for positive values), whereas floating-point numbers are rounded
>   toward the nearest even value:
>
> ```
> SELECT ROUND(1.5), ROUND(2.5) FROM DUAL;
>
> ROUND(1.5) ROUND(2.5)
> ---------- ----------
>          2          3
>
> SELECT ROUND(1.5f), ROUND(2.5f) FROM DUAL;
>
> ROUND(1.5F) ROUND(2.5F)
> ----------- -----------
>    2.0E+000    2.0E+000
> ```

Answer (score -2):

Just a guess:  the "f"/"F" suffix means floating point (thus, the scientific notation with mantissa and exponent).

"d"/"D" would perhaps be decimal??? (fixed precision decimal)

Google for Oracle Numeric Types, maybe :-(